# Customizing x-axis labels for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the following zoo object using the method `ggplot` from the package `ggplot2`:

```
library(zoo)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

vec =  c(41.27 ,50.35 ,59.18 ,60.93 ,61.35 ,32.13 ,41.18 ,43.69 ,58.48 ,65.02 ,44.61 ,64.89 ,57.4 ,68.67 ,53.6 ,49.2 ,51.85 ,
36.36 ,34.74 ,61.83 ,49.8 ,53.23 ,50.92 ,53.35 ,54.43 ,58.56 ,42.36 ,54.64 ,47.54 ,48.96 ,40.44 ,58 ,43.05 ,58.49 ,51.68 ,
42.22 ,37.79 ,58.7 ,46.69 ,44.68 ,50.48 ,54.92 ,50.23 ,52.49 ,43.93 ,40.7 ,56.64 ,44.46 ,45.81 ,50.4 ,49 ,49.37 ,53.95)
vec.idx =  c("2001-04-30", "2001-05-31", "2001-06-30", "2001-07-31", "2001-08-31", "2001-09-30", "2001-10-31", "2001-11-30", "2001-12-31", "2002-01-31", "2002-02-28",
"2002-03-31", "2002-04-30", "2002-05-31", "2002-06-30", "2002-07-31", "2002-08-31", "2002-09-30", "2002-10-31", "2002-11-30", "2002-12-31", "2003-01-31",
"2003-02-28", "2003-03-31", "2007-11-30", "2007-12-31", "2008-01-31", "2008-02-29", "2008-03-31", "2008-04-30", "2008-05-31", "2008-06-30", "2008-07-31",
"2008-08-31", "2008-09-30", "2008-10-31", "2008-11-30", "2008-12-31", "2009-01-31", "2009-02-28", "2009-03-31", "2010-05-31", "2010-06-30", "2010-07-31",
"2010-08-31", "2011-08-31", "2011-09-30", "2011-10-31", "2011-11-30", "2011-12-31", "2012-01-31", "2012-05-31", "2012-06-30")
vec.zoo = zoo(vec, order.by = as.Date(vec.idx, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

##### Plot

Time = as.Date(index(vec.zoo))
Value = coredata(vec.zoo)
Group <- c(0, cumsum(diff(index(vec.zoo)) > 31))
Names = paste("Period", Group+1, sep = " ")
start = start(vec.zoo)
end = end(vec.zoo)
x_breaks <- seq(start, end, by="1 year")
x_labels <- as.character(x_breaks, format="%b-%Y")

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
g <-ggplot(data.frame(Time, Value, Group, Names)) + geom_line(aes(x=as.Date(Time, format = "%y-%m-%d"), y=Value), color = "cadetblue4", size = 0.75) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size=7),axis.text.y = element_text(size=8), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10), plot.margin = unit(c(1,0.5,0.6,0.5), "inches") ) +
    facet_grid(~ Names, scales = "free_x", labeller = ) + 
    xlab("") + 
    ylab("Hit Rate") + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), expand = c(0, 0)) +
    scale_x_date(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = mean(vec.zoo), color = "red", size = 0.75)
```

Here is the plot I get:

[image]

I would like to place the `x-axis` labels ONLY at the points defined by the vector index. Currently, the plot is showing some random labels, for which there are no corresponding observations in my vector.

Could anyone please tell me how can I do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The labels are different because you explicitly told ggplot to construct the x axes separately for each panel. The labels in the final plot are correct. Perhaps you need to explain more clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: The labels on the final plot are not correct. If you look at the Groups, the only two points that should be on the last graph are 2012-05-31 and 2012-06-30. Those labels on the last graph are completely wrong.

Comment: Your assumption that ggplot only places labels at the exactly points in your data is incorrect. The labels are correct.

Comment: Well, how can I place only the labels that I have defined in the index vector?